# JSF: Save selected variable value in datatable for next view

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, tomahawk

I have a data table:

```
    <h:dataTable binding="#{table}" value="#{chooseKittens.kittenList}">
      <h:column>
        <p:commandLink value="#{chooseKittens.kittenList[table.rowIndex]}" action="#{chooseKittens.petKitten}"/>
      </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

The dataTable is a of links that will take you to a different page.  When I go to a different page, though, I want to save the value of the command link clicked so that I can display it in subsequent views.  Is there a way to do this without SessionScope?  I looked into t:saveState, but I'm not sure how to save just the variable clicked in a Datatable.  If SessionScope is the only thing available, is there a way to make the kittenList in a different scope? (The kitten list should change when a new kitten is added in the database, so it should be in RequestScope or ViewScope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share information between views there are two typically used alternatives you could consider.

1. **Pass information to the next view as a GET parameter**

   In this case you'll use a JSF component generating a plain navigational link and attach a query parameter to that link, like in:

   ```
   <h:link value="Next page" outcome="/view-kitten">
       <f:param name="id" value="#{kitten.id}"/>
   </h:link>
   ```

   In the receiving page the parameter is available via:

   ```
   <f:metadata>
       <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{kittenBean.id}/>
   </f:metadata>
   ```

   More excellent information can be found in [What can `<f:metadata>` and `<f:viewParam>` be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6377957/1820286)
2. **Pass information to the redirected view using `Flash`**

   In this case you're performing a redirect in an action method of a command component and will attach necessary data to the target view using `Flash` object:

   ```
   <h:commandButton value="Next page" action="#{bean.next}"/>
   ```

   with

   ```
   public String next() {
       //do business job
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("kitten", selectedKitten);
       return "/view-kitten?faces-redirect=true";
   }
   ```

   It will be available in the target view via EL with `#{flash.kitten}` or programmatically with `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("kitten")`.

   An extended example can be found in [JSF2.0 - How to get the values in other jsf page's bean in request scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15086915/1820286).

The last thing to note is: **don't abuse HTTP session**. You shouldn't pollute the session with information that belongs elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do alternative #1 using commandLink instead of a link? If possible I'd like to take advantage of the action tag.

Comment: You're welcome! You can attach the query parameter manually in your action method. But *be sure* to check out the reasons for creating a command component. Remember that its 'outcome' is non-crawlable and that without sending a redirect it forwards to the next view.